# How to make sure that while will stop in every respect

Tags: python, xbmc, kodi

I'm writing a script for KODI and I have discovered an infinite loop when there is a code error. This loop means that I have to login to another account or restart my computer to stop KODI.

My question is therefore, how do I make sure that `while` will stop in every respect?

---

This is just a part of the script, and that the codes is wrapped in a `try`. You also need to know that the `try` always works if I raise an error.

The problem in code is the `while` part e.g. at `p.get()`. This results in an error because I have not checked whether the work is completed before I call `get()` (I have not correct this error for your sake).

The problem is that even though I use `try`, an unexpected error will cause the `while` to not stop!

```
def browse(separate, page):
    [...]
    # Getting meta data and subtitles
    pools = {'metadata': [], 'subtitles': []}
    with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
        provider_meta = call_provider(PROVIDERS['meta_tmdb'])
        provider_subtitle = call_provider(PROVIDERS['subtitle_subscene'])
        for item in items:
            pools['metadata'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_meta.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
            pools['subtitles'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_subtitle.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
        pool_checklist = _create_checklist(pools)
        while not xbmc.abortRequested and not dialog.iscanceled():
            xbmc.sleep(100)
            # Check if are raise a error
            for p in pool_checklist:
                p.get()
            # Break when all requests are done 
            if all(p.ready() for p in pool_checklist):
                break
        else:
            return
    [...]

def _create_checklist(pools):
    plist = []
    for c in pools.values():
        for p in c:
            plist.append(p)
    return plist
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure whether the `while` only will be affected by the codes written in the `while` or whether there are other aspects that may affect the `while` process.

---

**UPDATE 2**

<del>A test to see if `get()` returns an error. Tested with Python 3.x and not with Python 2.x which is what KODI is using.</del>

---

**UPDATE 3**

A test to see if `get()` returns a raise error. Tested with Python 3.4.2 and Python 2.7.10.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing
import time

def func(x, i):
    if i == 10:
        raise Exception('ttt')
    return {'x':i}

def go():
    try:
        def callback(x):
            print('done: '+str(x['x']))

        pools = []
        with closing(Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
            for i in range(20):
                pools.append(pool.apply_async(func, args=(i,i), callback=callback))
            while not all(p.ready() for p in pools):
                time.sleep(1)

        list = map(lambda p: p.get(), pools)
        for l in list:
            print(l)
        print('Finished with the script')
    except:
        print('ERROR')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go()
```

---

**UPDATE 4**

The questions are still:

- Are the `while` only affected by the codes written in the `while` or can other aspects affect the `while` process?
- How do I make sure that the `while` will stop in every respect?

---

**UPDATE 5**

It does not appear that there is a solution where the `while` will stop in every respect.
Therefore, I think that the simple solution would be to check the pools after the `while`.

```
def browse(separate, page):
    [...]
    # Getting meta data and subtitles
    pools = {'metadata': [], 'subtitles': []}
    with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
        provider_meta = call_provider(PROVIDERS['meta_tmdb'])
        provider_subtitle = call_provider(PROVIDERS['subtitle_subscene'])
        for item in items:
            pools['metadata'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_meta.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
            pools['subtitles'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_subtitle.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
        pool_checklist = _create_checklist(pools)
        while not all(p.ready() for p in pool_checklist):
            if xbmc.abortRequested or dialog.iscanceled()
                return
            xbmc.sleep(100)
        # Check the pools for errors
        for p in pool_checklist:
            p.get()
    [...]

def _create_checklist(pools):
    plist = []
    for c in pools.values():
        for p in c:
            plist.append(p)
    return plist
```

Comment: From your use of `Pool` I'm guessing you're using multiprocessing. If a child process raises an exception, I don't think that will cause the main process to stop executing, so the while loop keeps going.

Comment: @Kevin Yes i am using multiprocessing :) But yes Pool will continue until it finish, however `get()` will return an error if there have been raise one.

Comment: Are you sure `get` will raise an error? What is the type of `p` there?

Comment: p is a pool :) I will post you a code example ... Ooh I have forgot I tested this code this Python 3.x not Python 2.x as KODI using...

Comment: @Kevin it works with Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred not at `get()`, but with target in `apply_async()`. This solution have therefore only made it possible to stop the process again.

The conclusion being that. The loop will continue although there is a fault with `Pool`, and therefore you can always exit the loop.

```
def browse(separate, page):
    [...]
    # Getting meta data and subtitles
    pools = {'metadata': [], 'subtitles': []}
    with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)) as pool:
        provider_meta = call_provider(PROVIDERS['meta_tmdb'])
        provider_subtitle = call_provider(PROVIDERS['subtitle_subscene'])
        for item in items:
            pools['metadata'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_meta.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
            pools['subtitles'].append(pool.apply_async(provider_subtitle.get, args=(item["info"]["code"], item["label"], item["info"]["year"]), callback=pool_stats))
        pool_checklist = _create_checklist(pools)
        # Loop
        while not all(p.ready() for p in pool_checklist):
            if xbmc.abortRequested or dialog.iscanceled():
                return
            xbmc.sleep(100)
        # Check the results for errors
        for p in pool_checklist:
            p.get()
    [...]
```

Furthermore be noted for Python 3.4.2 and 2.7.10, that `Pool` will only raise an error when it is completed, and any additional can `get()` be used to check the results for errors.